# creating Admin role with Laravel/Fortify

Tags: laravel-8

I am learning now to use Laravel and Fortify to create an application. I wanted to create an Admin user that will create users from within the application. The app is not for public use, but an internal app as a company management tool.
The login is working ok, but I have the register view in the app environment so, at the moment, any user can create other users (the app is in construction, not in use), but when I try to access to create a new user I get redirected to /home, and not to the register view.
I understand this is because the user is already created and Fortify understands there is no need to register again (useful for public apps). Is there any way I can let users to register other users??
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Finally I created an almost custom functionality.
I created a resource UserController and added the registration form to a new view in the dashboard "Register user", added the link users.create to redirect to the registration view and included the {{ route('users.store') }} link in the form's action.
Then, in the UserController's store method I used the code from Fortify of the RegisterUserController class, the method store, exactly the line "event(new Registered($user = $creator->create($request->all())));".
And now I can register users from other users sessions!!
Now I need to implement the roles so only admin users can register other users!!!
Here is the code if you are interested on in!! Enjoy!!

routes/web.php

```
Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
```

App/Http/Controlles/UserController.php -> method store

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param CreatesNewUsers $creator
 * @return void
 */
public function store(Request $request, CreatesNewUsers $creator)
{
    // Copied and pasted from the store method in the RegisterUserController class of Fortify
    // The code in origin has been commented to avoid duplications
    event(new Registered($user = $creator->create($request->all())));
}
```

navigation-dropdown.blade.php added one more link to the nav

```
<div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('users.create') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('dashboard')">
                    {{ __('Register user') }}
                </x-jet-nav-link>
            </div>
```

register-user.blade.php

```
<x-app-layout>
<x-slot name="header">
    <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
        {{ __('Register user') }}
    </h2>
</x-slot>

<div class="py-12">
    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-xl sm:rounded-lg">
            <div class="container p-5">
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('users.store') }}">
                    @csrf

                    <div>
                        <x-jet-label for="name" value="{{ __('Name') }}" />
                        <x-jet-input id="name" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="name" :value="old('name')" required autofocus autocomplete="name" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="mt-4">
                        <x-jet-label for="email" value="{{ __('Email') }}" />
                        <x-jet-input id="email" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="email" name="email" :value="old('email')" required />
                    </div>

                    <div class="mt-4">
                        <x-jet-label for="password" value="{{ __('Password') }}" />
                        <x-jet-input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="mt-4">
                        <x-jet-label for="password_confirmation" value="{{ __('Confirm Password') }}" />
                        <x-jet-input id="password_confirmation" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="password" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
                        <x-jet-button class="ml-4">
                            {{ __('Register user') }}
                        </x-jet-button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Pau, I suggest you not to use `request->all()` because this is an open door for damages. Instead you should use `request->validated()` and in your validation rules you should include al needed variables in order to perform a strict control on what information you let get into your database. There are several posts on the net about it. Here is one of that. https://m-elfeqy.medium.com/the-danger-of-using-request-all-and-how-to-protect-it-f07c6787da08